# Entity Framework Related Entity too much load time

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC5 along with EF6 to develop an application. I'm using SQL Server Express for database. I have two tables/entities in the database.

Vehicle - Contains Information about the vehicles

GsmDeviceLog - Contains data received from GPS Tracker Fit in the vehicle.

My GsmDeviceLogs table currently has around 20K records and it takes around 90 Seconds to execute the below code. Just to fetch one record(i.e. The Last Record).

Here is the code:

```
var dlog = db.Vehicles.Find(2).GsmDeviceLogs.LastOrDefault();
```

When I try to open the table using Server explorer it shows ALL the data with in 5-10 seconds. Can anyone help me get the details loaded quickly on the page as well.

Thanks for reading and paying attention to the question. 
Can anyone suggest any means to reduce the time.

Comment: What is `Find` returning? `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` ?

Comment: DbSet of Vehicle type.

Comment: I think your piece of code is pulling all records from the table, then on the client side, doing a descending sort, giving you the first row. Can you see if memory usage goes up significantly after running that specific line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should look like this:

```
var dlog = db.Vehicles
    .Where(v => v.Id == 2)
    .SelectMany(v => v.GsmDeviceLogs)
    .OrderByDescending(gdl => gdl.Id) // or order by some datetime
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In your original query you are loading the `Vehicle` with `Find`. Then accessing the `GsmDeviceLogs` collection loads **all** logs of that vehicle into memory by lazy loading and then you pick the last one from the loaded collection in memory. It's probably the loading of all logs that consumes too much time.

The query above is executed completely in the database and returns only one `GsmDeviceLog` record. Side note: You must use `OrderByDescending(...).FirstOrDefault` here because `LastOrDefault` is not supported with LINQ to Entities.

Comment: It gives a compilation error in OrderByDescending line. It doesn't recognize gdl as GsmDeviceLog type.

Comment: @AshishCharan: Is `.Id` perhaps the problem? You have to replace it by the correct key of your `GsmDeviceLog` entity.

Comment: No.I tried to sort it using TimeOfLog Field. But it doesn't recognize that.

Comment: @AshishCharan: Ah, sorry, you must replace `Select` by `SelectMany`, see my edited code above.

Comment: Works with the edit. Lemme check the load time. Also, Isn't it possible with the nav. properties. That only one should come.?

Comment: @AshishCharan: Not with lazy loading. It will always load the whole collection into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your Linq query is inefficient. try doing `db.Vehicles.Single( x => x.Id).GsmDeviceLogs.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault()` or whatever your primary keys are

Comment: It results in same time.

Comment: Then you should look at your SQL layout. 90 seconds is ALOT for 20k records.

Comment: But it opens it up very quickly in server explorer. I don't understand the reason.